# trying to connect with azure AuthenticationResult, but getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/jwt/JWTParser

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

trying to connect with azure AuthenticationResult ,through rest service call but getting error saying

> {
>       "code": 500,
>       "message": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/jwt/JWTParser" }

```
private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(String username, String password)
        throws Exception {
    AuthenticationContext context;
    AuthenticationResult result;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", CLIENT_ID, username, password, null);

        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just tested with the same code, no error occurred. May I know the version of your ADAL library? Mine is 1.6.2

Comment: 1.6.3 
it worked thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got similar error. Its due to runtime dependency class un availability. Try adding this **nimbus-jose-jwt JAR Version 4.2**.

The link is https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/4.2/source-code

The way to find out this error is, search with your class name com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser jar and you must be finding that class in the jar before adding it. Try it and tell us.

Answer (score 4):

Did you add ADAL libraries to your build file (pom.xml or build.gradle)? Anyway, look for the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```